# I cant install NODEJS in CENTOS... why?

Tags: node.js, centos5

Ive wget a version that have .configure of NODEJS (node-v0.8.3) Be couse the latest version doesnt have .configue o make or makeintall.. (Just found "how to" with ./configue)... My server is  CENTOS 5.. I wnat to install NODEJS.. need help!   Im gettins the following error:

```
xxx@xxx [/usr/local/src/node-v0.8.3]# ./configure
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': [],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'host_arch': 'x64',
                 'node_install_npm': 'true',
                 'node_install_waf': 'true',
                 'node_prefix': '',
                 'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_shared_v8': 'false',
                 'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
                 'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
                 'node_use_etw': 'false',
                 'node_use_openssl': 'true',
                 'target_arch': 'x64',
                 'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating  ./config.gypi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 400, in <module>
    pprint.pformat(output, indent=2) + "\n")
  File "./configure", line 396, in write
    f = open(filename, 'w+')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './config.gypi'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: are you installing using sudo ?

Comment: how to sudo ./configure? give syntax error

Comment: on the prompt just type sudo configure , should work

Comment: sudo: configure: command not found

Comment: and sudo ./configure , what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: <pre>xxx@xxx [/usr/local/src/node-v0.8.3]# sudo ./configure
  File "./configure", line 273
    o['default_configuration'] = 'Debug' if options.debug else 'Release'</pre>
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of Python do you have installed on your system (check with `python -V`)? The Node build scripts require Python 2.6 or 2.7 (*maybe* 2.5, definitely not 3.x).

Comment: node 0.8.x requires Python 2.6. Make sure you have all the requirements https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 11 2013, 20:38:01)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt know anything about linux... But I did have succes with these commands:

```
1: me@server.com [/]# cd ~
2: me@server.com [~]# mkdir node
3: me@server.com [~]# cd node
4: me@server.com [~/node]# wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.4/node-v0.10.4.tar.gz
5: me@server.com [~/node]# tar zxvf node-v0.10.4.tar.gz
6: me@server.com [~/node]# cd node-v0.10.4
7: me@server.com [~/node/node-v0.10.4]# ./configure
8: me@server.com [~/node/node-v0.10.4]# make
9: me@server.com [~/node/node-v0.10.4]# make install
```

I was getting privileges errors in Centos 5... thanks everybody who helps!

Comment: Just an fyi, you really should run all the commands except for #9 as a normal user. Running everything as root is unneeded and exposes your system to additional risk.

Comment: I get a Syntax error when running `./configure` - `File "./configure", line 433 fpu = 'vfpv3' if armv7 else 'vfpv2' SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Why is it so difficult to install NodeJS on CentOS?

Comment: actually, the configure file is a python script, and you should have python 2.7.x installed to run it